# Are there any Ruby on Rail Gems or Plug-ins that performs web queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, screen-scraping, web-scraping, excel-web-query

I need build in web query capability similar to what you can do in Excel for a project that I'm working on.  Has anyone come across a gem, plug-in or application with this capability.

Clarification: To clarify, the excel web query features that I'm trying to create is the ability to extract data from specified tables on a web page.  A good example would be if given a particular ticker symbol the web query would be able to submit the ticker symbol and then extract and display output table.

I've looked at fork on project like nokogiri, celerity and other screen scraping apps but have not come across what I'm looking for yet.

Thanks for your insights, ideas and suggestions.

Comment: You should probably clarify which aspects of the Excel feature you're looking for. The UI? The transformation it does? The extraction of data from tables into an array structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in possible screen scraping gems/plugins checkout: [regexp_crawler](https://github.com/flyerhzm/regexp_crawler), [spidr](https://github.com/postmodern/spidr), [scrAPI](https://github.com/assaf/scrapiu) or [mechanize](https://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize)

Comment: i love mechanize.  simple, elegant, and you can parse via CSS or XPath.